# Is it possible to make passive voice of following sentences

Tags: grammar, tenses, passive-voice

What will be the passive of these sentences? Are 'going' and 'go' intransitive verbs in these sentences?

> I am going to school
>
> I go to London

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's more or less _possible_ (School is being gone to by me, London is gone to by me), but this doesn't sound like a fully fleshed-out question. Have you done research into this? Why do you think you can/can't make a passive construction here? (By the way, welcome to EL&U!)

Comment: When the subject of an active sentence is "I", the passive form usually doesn't sound very good.

Comment: @GregLee: _I hit the dog_ -> _The dog is hit by me_. No problem, I think, and certainly not sounding worse than _the dog is hit by John_. I think the _verb_ is more to "blame" than the subject.

Comment: Thank you Sir

I need some more explanation, thank you so much

Comment: Some constructions sound outlandish as passives, especially with by-phrases. 'London is gone to by ...' and 'School is gone to by ...' don't sound right. 'London is visited by [_many people_, but not usually _me_]'  and 'School is attended by' [again, a more distant group is better]' are fine.

Comment: Please anybody help me please i will be very thankful to you..

Comment: The rule for Passive requires a transitive sentence as input. A transitive sentence has a subject noun phrase, a transitive verb, and a direct object. The sentences you provided contain subject noun phrases, but they do not contain transitive verbs or direct objects. _Go_ is not a transitive verb. Therefore, Passive may not be applied to these sentences at all.

Comment: I am going to school (active)

is it correct to make passive construction of this sentence like,

"Action of going to school is being happened by me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the intransitive verb "go" not having a direct object makes it difficult to construct a passive form. You would need to use a transitive verb in order to construct a passive form.

- I am going to school.

  - --> I am approaching the school.
  - --> The school is being approached by me.
- I go to London.

  - --> I am approaching London.
  - --> London is being approached by me.